# tensorflow how to feed many input images (array of (batchsize, height, width, channels)) to tensorflow Conv2d for object detection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, object-detection

I am having some difficulty feeding training imagery into a Conv2d model (for object detection). My questions are:

1. How do I properly feed a Conv2d model training images?
2. For object detection, how do I properly define the classifier output for 2 class output (using categorical_cross_entropy, since number of classes will change in future)?

I am getting an error when trying to fit model, which I believe is for the classifier output (see below code and error). I only have 2 classes but am trying to use sparse categorical cross entropy. Also, the params are zero for input and average_pooling layers, which seem wrong to me.

A link to my full code with test images and labels: https://github.com/arojas314/data-sharing.git

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Snippet of model:

```py
'''
Feature extractor is the CNN that is made up of convolution and pooling layers.
'''
def feature_extractor(inputs):
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, activation='relu', kernel_size=3, input_shape=(424, 424, 3))(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D((2, 2))(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D((2, 2))(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D((2, 2))(x)

    return x

'''
dense_layers adds a flatten and dense layer.
This will follow the feature extraction layers
'''
def dense_layers(inputs):
    x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    return x


'''
Classifier defines the classification output.
This has a set of fully connected layers and a softmax layer.
'''
def classifier(inputs):
    classification_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax', name = 'classification')(inputs)
    # classification_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax', name = 'classification')(inputs) # works but so should above
    return classification_output


'''
This function defines the regression output for bounding box prediction.
Note that we have four outputs corresponding to (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
'''
def bounding_box_regression(inputs):
    bounding_box_regression_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = '4', name = 'bounding_box')(inputs)
    return bounding_box_regression_output


def final_model(inputs):
    feature_cnn = feature_extractor(inputs)
    dense_output = dense_layers(feature_cnn)

    '''
    The model branches here.
    The dense layer's output gets fed into two branches:
    classification_output and bounding_box_output
    '''
    classification_output = classifier(dense_output)
    bounding_box_output = bounding_box_regression(dense_output)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = [classification_output, bounding_box_output])

    return model


def define_and_compile_model(inputs):
    model = final_model(inputs)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss = {'classification' : 'categorical_crossentropy',
                          'bounding_box' : 'mse'
                         },
                  metrics = {'classification' : 'accuracy',
                             'bounding_box' : 'mse'
                            })
    # Returns full and compiled model
    return model


# Create model
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(424, 424, 3))
model = define_and_compile_model(inputs)

# print model layers
model.summary()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems you did not one-hot encode your object class labels, your two questions seem unrelated to the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I changed to "sparse_categorical_crossentropy". I am still left with some questions. How come params are 0 for input, average_pooling2d, and flatten layers?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy After changing to sparse_categorical_crossentropy, I receive `nan` as bounding_box_loss and bounding_box_mse, while classification_loss is `nan` and classification_accuracy is 0.0. Also, the params for input, average_pooling2d, and flatten layers are set to zero after compiling.